# javascript: how to use a hidden tag to direct text update of larger object without line breaks added?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

Of course, we can update all the text of an object like this:

```
document.getElementById(objId).innerHTML = "some text we like";
```

What I'm looking to do is update a subset of existing text, with the target to be replaced being identified by a hidden tag. So, for example instead of having to parse something like this in my own code:

```
<p> Here's a huge block of text, many lines long and
**here's the part I want to update,** buried within it and yet there's even more afterwards.</p>
```

...instead I want to (and can) do something like this:

```
<p> Here's a huge block of text, many lines long and <option id="target">**here's the part I want to update,**</option> buried within it and yet there's even more afterwards.</p>
```

...And then update that with:

```
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = "replacement text we like";
```

Unremarkably, this works, BUT, it has the effect of adding line breaks, as if there was a `<br>` tag where there's `<option>` and `</option>`.

Here's the EFFECTIVE result of that call:

```
<p> Here's a huge block of text, many lines long and<br> replacement text we like<br> buried within it and yet there's even more afterwards.</p>
```

How can I do this WITHOUT the line breaks being inserted?

Comment: use inline elment (like span) instead (option is a block element)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a `<span>` tag instead of a `<div>`. Here is a working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6bm071e8/).

Comment: Exactly! Works great, thanks. I already tried to mark this as correct but it says I have to wait a few minutes! Talk about fast! :-)

Answer (score 2):

Elements like `<option>` or `<div>` are block elements. You need to use an inline element so you can use `<span>` instead of `<option>`:

```js
function myFoo() {
  document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = "replacement text we like";
}
```

```html
<p> Here's a huge block of text, many lines long and <span id="target">**here's the part I want to update,**</span> buried within it and yet there's even more afterwards.</p>

<button id="btn" onclick="myFoo()">Change Text!</button>
```